# Deploy ASP.NET web application to Mono on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, macos, mono

I am an experienced ASP.NET developer and familiar with Visual Studio and IIS. But I'd like to deploy ASP.NET applications to Mac OS X using Mono. I've done a LOT of searching on the web and can't a simple straight forward way to deploy a site on a Mac. Everything I've found does NOT give the whole picture.

I've downloaded the current Mono release (3.2.4) from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html. But I don't think the installation package is complete. For example, I can't find any mod_mono compiled binaries. The mod_mono.conf file is supposed to reference mod_mono.so, but I can NOT find installed anywhere from the installation package. I found the mod_mono source at on a link from the above page, but don't know how to compile and deploy.

Also creating the mod_mono.conf is another issue. There is a configuration tool at http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/Default.aspx, but it doesn't work in my setup.

The only success I've had, is with the xsp server tool. I think it is meant for testing and NOT deployment.

BTW, I am running OS X Mavericks 10.9.1. I only want to deploy to Mono. The development is done under Windows with Visual Studio.

Could someone guide me? I am obviously missing some steps.